# UIImageView's start animation does not animate flipped images

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, animation, uiimageview

I have a set of images facing one side(Man facing right side), and I'm flipping it using this method and then adding it into a uiimageview's animationImages.  However after adding in the flipped images, and then start to animate, the animation is still facing the right side.

```
manRunAnimations = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 64, 64)];
NSArray *manAniRunArray = @[[UIImage imageNamed:@"robot1"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"robot2"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"robot3"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"robot4"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"robot5"],
                            [UIImage imageNamed:@"robot6"],
                            ];


manRunAnimationsf = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 64, 64)];

NSMutableArray *flippedRunAnimationImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for( UIImage *image in manAniRunArray)
{
    UIImage * flippedImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:image.CGImage scale:image.scale orientation:UIImageOrientationRightMirrored];
    [flippedRunAnimationImages addObject:flippedImage];
}

manRunAnimationsf.animationImages = (NSArray *)flippedRunAnimationImages;

testImgView.image = [manRunAnimationsf.animationImages objectAtIndex:0];
manRunAnimationsf.animationDuration = runAnimationSpeedSlider.value;
[manRunAnimationsf startAnimating];
```

I've even tested it using

```
testImgView.image = [manRunAnimationsf.animationImages objectAtIndex:5];
```

This would display one of the flipped images properly on screen just before I do a

```
[manRunAnimationsf startAnimating];
```

Once it starts, the animations are not flipped at all!!

Anyone know why?

Comment: You guys think is somehow related to the cached image from using "imageNamed" method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't believe no one knows why, but I found way around it.  Is to add the following before I startAnimating:

```
    manRunAnimationsf.transform = CGAffineTransformMake(-1,0,0,1,0,0);
```

I didn't even need to do the CGImage flips in that for loop.

But the manual image flip should have worked with the imageWithCGImage method, and I really want to know why!!  You guys disappoint me. :p

Comment: Anyone with insightful comments?

Comment: i'm suffering the same dilemma with no possible answer as of yet